# how to create multiple boxplots from the same dataframe?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have a data frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame(var_1 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), 
                 var_2 = c(21,23,34,45,23,56,76,54,65),
                 var_3 = c(6,5,4,3,5,7,3,2,5),
                 label = c(1,1,1,2,1,2,2,1,2))
```

I want to create side by side (or  tile) box plots such that the first box plot is

```
boxplot(var_1~label, df)
```

the second box plot is

```
boxplot(var_2~label, df)
```

and so on. Is there a way to do this without me having to type box plot command each time? For example, some command that iteratively matches all the columns against `label` and draw a box plot for each?

Comment: [`ggplot::facet_wrap()`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/facet_wrap.html) makes it really easy if you also `tidyr::pivot_longer()` first

Comment: @DanAdams could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `ggplot::facet_wrap()` makes it easy to make a bunch of panels of a graph from one dataset. However for it to work the variable that defines the different panels has to be in a single column. In this case that means you have to get from the 'wide' format to a 'long' format of your data. For this I suggest `tidyr::pivot_longer()`. Last point is that you need to treat your `label` as a `factor` otherwise you won't get separate boxes as you do in base R because I think that converts the x variable into a factor by default which {ggplot2} won't do (although it will give an informative warning). Finally, if you want to have separate `y` axes for each plot you can set `scales = "free_y"` inside `facet_wrap()`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(var_1 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), 
                 var_2 = c(21,23,34,45,23,56,76,54,65),
                 var_3 = c(6,5,4,3,5,7,3,2,5),
                 label = c(1,1,1,2,1,2,2,1,2))

df %>%
  pivot_longer(-label) %>%
  ggplot(aes(factor(label), value)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(vars(name), nrow = 1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>